# Android alarms, service as not been called

Tags: android, alarms

In my activity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

Toast.makeText(this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The class to be called:

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

With this code, MyAlarmService as not been called. Why?
This code removed from a sample, which therefore tested is functioning correctly. Will I have forgotten anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your service is started properly. There is problem with Toast in service.

Try to change `Toast.makeText()` to `Log.d()` and see if record appears in your Logcat.

Problem with Toast in service has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298083/toast-in-a-self-running-service).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be right. I also tried this example in my code and it worked fine.

I think the problem is in the Manifest. You need to declare the service in the Manifest of your project like this:

```
< service android:name=".MyAlarmService" />
```

Comment: Is not the problem, my manifest have that line... Now i find other way to solve this problem, thank you ;)