# Cannot Run Tasks in Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-service-binding

I know this is a basic question, I am new to android service. I have done research on Google and StackOverflow. There are many question in stackoverflow related to or similar to my topic, But I couldn't able to get the proper answer and I am being diverted to different topics.

This is the simple test code I am running.

```
public class Service extends android.app.Service {

private Handler mHandler;

private void ping() {
    try {
        Log.e("Tag", "Success");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Ping", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "In onStartCommand");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    scheduleNext();
}

private void scheduleNext() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { ping(); }
    }, 3000);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int x, int y) {
    mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
    ping();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

}
```

In this a Toast message pops up and Log message printed for every 3 seconds, It works even when the app is minimized. But when i completely quit the app, There is no Toast or Log printed. In this [SO ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298083/toast-in-a-self-running-service) in clearly says why Toast message cannot called without the UI. And I cannot print the LOG as the process is being killed.

**Basically, I want the service to run in background for every 5 min and need to get the data from online. How should I implement the service? and any example code or tutorials are appreciated?**

Comment: Use `AlarmManager` (all Android versions) or `JobScheduler` (Android 5.0+).

Comment: @CommonsWare Alarm Manager Worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a Service, by default it runs in the same process as whatever component started it.  When the process that component is running in quits, so too does the Service.  In order to start a Service in its own process, you need to do the following in the manifest:

```
    <service
        android:name=".Service"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":separate_service_process"
        android:stopWithTask="false" >
    </service>
```

Putting a colon in front of the label for the `android:process` attribute tells the system to start the service in a separate process, and the `android:stopWithTask` attribute will tell the system to keep the service alive even when the component that started it stops.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html for more information on the manifest settings (the `stopWithTask` attribute is part of the `ServiceInfo` class).

Now start your service using `startService(Intent)` and you should be all set.  Good luck!

PS--I'd recommend renaming your Service class to something unique to avoid confusion with the base Service class.